# Curly bracket with "return" keyword

Tags: javascript

```
var calculator = function ()
{
   function abc() { return (2+3); }

   return {
        addFun: abc
   }
}();


var calcu = function () {
    function abc() { return (3+4); }

    return 
    {
        addFun: abc
    }
}();


$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(calculator.addFun());
    **alert(calcu.addFun());**
});
```

What is difference between calculator and calcu function?  calcu function gives error when it execute.

Difference is only that curly bracket is next line in "calcu". It is work fine if I remove next and put curly bracket with "return" keyword.

Please explain why so?

Comment: yes, semi-colon insertion is different after a return statement than it is elsewhere...

Answer (score 5):

It's being parsed as this:

```
return; // returns undefined
// a block:
{
    addFun: abc // syntax error!
};
```

because of automatic semicolon insertion.

Change it to:

```
return {
     addFun: abc
};
```

Comment: Too many edits!  It will become a community wiki!

Comment: @Man Edits 5 minutes after posting don't count :P

Comment: Nitpick: the error arises because `undefined` has no method named `addFun`. There's no syntax error.

Comment: Or put parens around what you're returning.

Comment: @Blender Actually, `addFun` is parsed as a label and `abc` is a `ReferenceError`. But yes, technically it's not a syntax error.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow: Are you sure? I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addFun' of undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

It's called [automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.io/#x7.9):

> When a `continue`, `break`, `return`, or `throw` token is encountered and a *LineTerminator* is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is automatically inserted after the `continue`, `break`, `return`, or `throw` token.

Since there's a newline right after your `return` statement, a semicolon is inserted automatically, turning your code into:

```
return;
{
    addFun: abc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Return is a tricky keyword in JavaScript. In the first example, you are returning an anonymous object to the calculator function, and in the second example you are returning no values. JavaScript will interpret the second function like this:

```
var calcu = function() { 
    function abc() ...

    return; // return undefined
    {
          addFun: abc
    }
```

Notice the semi colon is interpreted after the return keyword and thus the calcu function will return nothing.

Comment: Yep, this is the case where parens around what you're returning removes all chance of the interpreter guessing your intentions wrong.  I'm often criticized for using parens around my return values, but this is exactly the case where it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
return 
{
    addFun: abc
}
```

This is wrong because JavaScript would execute return and will get out.
This should be

```
return {
    addFun: abc
}
```

Comment: @Travesty3 sorry copy paste error ;)

Comment: No problem. But the lack of code-styling was making your answer appear wrong. So I wanted to make sure it got fixed before you got a ton of downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at linting tools such as [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) to avoid this and many other errors, here is it's output:

[image]

What happens is that this section:

```
return 
{
    addFun: abc
}
```

is being interpreted as two statements, a return void (the function returns void immediatelly) plus an object expression containing addFun that is not assigned to anything.